# How to translate Olson timezone keys in symfony

Tags: symfony, internationalization, xliff

I have an API REST service that gives me back the list of the supported timezones in my DB (postgres). Something like this:

```
{
  "quantity_name": "timezone",
  "measures": [
    {
      "measure": "Arctic/Longyearbyen",
      "utc_offset": "02:00:00",
      "is_dst": true
    },
    {
      "measure": "GMT+0",
      "utc_offset": "00:00:00",
      "is_dst": false
    },
    ...
```

What I would like is giving back a translated "measure" field, according to the user preferences. Is there a translation file about this? A ready-to-use service? A bundle? Thank you

**Update**
I'm thinking about a `XLIFF` file, hoping that someone has already translated them into some language (Spanish, Italian, French, etc), but I'm not finding them. If anyone knows an open xliff repository please share it here!

Answer (score 1):

Time zone names have been translated as part of the Unicode CLDR project. You can find them [here](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/verify/zones/index.html). Or you can use the translations from libraries like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/): some ICU functionality has been wrapped in PHP Intl.

I am not aware of any open XLIFF repositories: XLIFF is designed to support a translation process, and it contains much information that is not relevant any more after translation has been completed. There are a few sites for sharing translation memories, but I have no hands-on experience with any of them.